# Could it harm my career to go for a promotion too early?

Tags: career-development, promotion

I have been in my current role for 10 months and this is my first job after university, I applied for a junior Developer in Test role and was offered the next step up (Developer in Test). I was previously at a training camp for 3 months learning test automation and web development.

Since I have joined the company, we have moved forward with a lot of new technologies which I have had a big role in within my team and now the rest of the company is following suit. This means that with the new technologies I am one of experienced members in not only my team but the company and I do try to push new technologies not just for testing but also development. I regularly have to assist senior members with the newer technologies, go on calls with clients, and give demo's of what we have been implementing.

This gives me the feeling that I have earned the opportunity to go for a promotion to senior Developer in Test due to my skills and what I have added to the company. However when the role becomes available I will have only been at the company for slightly longer than 1 year with the same amount of experience.

Is it too early to be applying for a senior role?

Will it affect my career with my company applying and getting rejected or would they not even consider me for the role? When I discussed this with my team leader in my first few months of the job he said that if I carry on working at a similar level he doesn't see a reason why I couldn't apply and be seriously considered, but I'm just worried that the 'higher ups' might see me as wanting too much too fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay so you've been in professional work for 10 months.

> Is it too early to be applying for a senior role?

Pretty much, Yes. *However* you have **nothing to lose** as they aren't going to fire you because you applied for a promotion in the form of a senior position. It's not going to negatively affect you, it just shows you believe you have the ability to get to that position.

Although it is *extremely* rare that someone goes from junior with 10 months experience to a senior post which tends to be 10+ years of experience **at least**.

> When I discussed with my team leader in my first few months of the job he said that if I carry on working at a similar level he doesn't see a reason why I couldn't apply and be seriously considered.

Then discuss it with him again. See what he's saying now as it's closer to that time. If he said you could be seriously considered then I don't see another reason as to why you wouldn't at least attempt it.

> but I'm worried that the 'higher ups' might see me as wanting too much too fast.

This completely depends on your company, these progressions may occur often. This is for you to find out, speak to your supervisor and see what he thinks about the whole situation. He knows what you can do and what is expected of a senior within your organisation.

Comment: While it is unlikely, I went from Junior -> mid-level -> senior in 2 years hopping between 3 jobs (mid-level was toxic, left after 3 months). It's possible, but very unlikely to internally promote a junior to a senior unless they were unfairly employed in the first place.

Comment: @JayGould Although possible, even less possible with only 10 months

Comment: I disagree that it takes 10 years to go from jr to sr in a dev role.  Jr to regular dev should be doable within 1 to 2 years.  Regular to Sr *within* 2 years of that - worst case is 3 years.  By 10 years you ought to be a Development Manager if you want to do that job.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it affect my career with my company applying and getting rejected
>   or would they not even consider me for the role?

Previous job I joined the customer service team and within 3 weeks moved to a specialist department, first day in the new department there was a position advertised (which was filled already as someone was working as an interim) however I still applied.

2 things go from there, you show where you want to go and if after careful consideration they feel you are already there then win win!

Rejection is the default if you don't apply...if you do apply you have a chance :)